# How to hide fragment with transaction fast as possible - Android?

Tags: android

My current activity contains fragments. I want to open new Activity on button click from current activity. New Activity is transparent, and because of that I have to hide fragment from prev Activity. No buttons from prev activity should be shown under new Activity's buttons. I've done that. It works. Only problem is because there is little pause between switching these two Activities. Obviusly hiding fragment of prev activity takes time. Can I make it hide fragment faster? Here is my code:

```
    @Override
public void onArcadeButtonClicked() {

    fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.hide(fragments[MAINMENU]);
            transaction.commit();      

    Intent i= new Intent(this,ArcadeMapActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

When i remove first four lines and only call new Intent there is no pause, new Activity is shown immediately, but fragment from old Activity stays visible under new Activity. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: you do you need an activity if you need a transparent activity. you can use `AlertDialog`s.

Comment: instead of creating new activity you can create transparent fragment and use transaction.replace() to replace current fragment with new one. I think this will work faster

Comment: Yap Varun, maybe but my project is almost finished...it would required many changes, for which I dont have time at the moment...I've should consider that more earlier :( I need fastes solution...